# Given several axioms and a property, how do I structure a proof of the property?

Tags: dafny

Given the following axioms:

```
A>=0
forall n :: n>=0 && n<N1 ==> n < A
N1 >= A
```

We want to prove  that `N1==A` using Dafny.

I have tried following Dafny program:

```
function N1(n: int,A: int):bool
  requires A>=0 && n>=0 
{
  if n==0 && A<=n
  then true else
  if n>0 
    && A<=n  
    && forall k::
       (if 0<=k && k<n 
        then A>k else true) 
  then true
  else false
}

lemma Theorem(n: int,A: int)
requires A>=0 && n>=0 && N1(n,A)
ensures n==A;
{ }
```

But Dafny fails to prove that. Is there a way to `N1==A` from the given axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dafny can prove it just fine, but it needs a bit more help:

```
predicate P(n:int, N1:int)
{
  n >= 0 && n < N1
}

lemma Lem(A:int, N1:int)
  requires A>=0
  requires forall n :: P(n, N1) ==> n < A
  requires  N1 >= A
  ensures N1 == A 
{ 
  if(N1 > A)
  {
    assert A >= 0 && A < N1;
    assert P(A, N1);
    assert A < A;
    assert false;
  }
  assert N1 <= A;  
}
```

The proof proceeds by contradiction, and is quite standard. The only Dafny specific bit of the proof is that we have to give a name to the property that `n >= 0 && n < N1`. We give the property the name `P` by introducing it as a predicate. The requirement to introduce P comes from the interaction of Dafny with some details of how quantifier instantiation (trigger matching) works in the underlying SMT solver (Z3).

You may alternatively prefer to write the lemma this way:

```
lemma Lem(A:int, N1:int)
  requires A>=0
  requires forall n :: P(n, N1) ==> n < A
  requires  N1 >= A
  ensures N1 == A 
{ 
   calc ==>
   {
     N1 > A;
        {assert P(A, N1);}
     A < A;
     false;
   }  
   assert N1 <= A;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer. I have a small doubt what is the use of assertion A< A which is always false.

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction. I make an assumption using the if statement, then I derive something which is equivalent to false, in this case A < A. Then, since I have derived false inside the conditional, we get to use the negation of it condition as a fact on the line after the closing curly bracket of the conditional. This is how dafny supports the standard first order logic proof technique of proof by contradiction